# Save SpaCy PhraseMatcher to disk

Tags: spacy

I am creating a phrasematcher with SpaCy like this:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

nlp = spacy.load("en")
label = "SKILL"
print("Creating the matcher...")

start = time.time()
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
for i in list_skills:
    matcher.add(label, None, nlp(i))
```

My list_skills is very big, so the creation of matcher takes a long time, and I reuse it very often. Is there a way to save the matcher to disk, and reload it later on without having to recreate it everytime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save time some time initially by using `nlp.tokenizer.pipe()` to process your texts:

```
for doc in nlp.tokenizer.pipe(list_skills):
    matcher.add(label, None, doc)
```

This just tokenizes, which is much faster than running the full `en` pipeline. If you're using certain `attr` settings with `PhraseMatcher`, you may need `nlp.pipe()` instead, but you should get an error if this is the case.

You can pickle a `PhraseMatcher` to save it to disk. Unpickling is not extremely fast because it has to reconstruct some internal data structures, but it should be a quite a bit faster than creating the `PhraseMatcher` from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pickle

filename = 'finalized_matcher.sav'

pickle.dump(matcher, open(filename, 'wb'))
 

loaded_matcher = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).